# How to create GUI programs with Code::Blocks

Tags: c++

Previously I used Visual Studio for my C++ programmings. But some cost effects I had to change my IDE, so I chose Code::Clocks (12.11). But I can't find a way to develop GUI applications with C::B. Is there any way to develop GUIs with C::B?

Comment: What does an IDE have to do with developing GUIs? Are you looking for a WYSIWYG forms designer that works with CB?

Comment: I mean something like Visual Studio's drag n' drop designing

Comment: Code block is an IDE. You don't create gui apps using CB just like you don't create gui apps using a terminal.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, You can develop GUIs with CodeBlocks if you have [GTK](http://www.gtk.org/)+ or [wxWidget](http://www.wxwidgets.org/) Libraries. You can use one of them at your own choice. CodeBlocks can't use them until you download and install them, So you have to perform some actions to make them usable in CodeBlocks. For GTK+ configuration steps see [this](http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=16468.0) and for wxWidget see [this](http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/CodeBlocks_Setup_Guide).

Comment: So, basically with the default code::blocks libraries, I can't do any GUI project ! Am I right ? I have to download other libraries for that. OK, I understand now, there are requirements for everything in programming, if I want to do some simple `.exe` or other simple MS-Dos applications, then the basic libraries are enough, if I want more then I have to get the required libraries for any higher projects than `.exe` or MS-Dos projects.

Answer (score 5):

I create Win32 gui apps all the time with Code::Blocks 20.3 (uses MinGW-W64 project compiler) because I code them using the Win32 api.  This is the manual way of doing things, and it works great;  the down-side is that you must learn the Win32 api. (its an aspiring challenge, but for an experienced C/C++ programmer and some google skills, its doable)
Many programmers believe that gui apps must be built with a graphical builder (GTK+, wxWidgets, etc) but not true.  In fact, in the stock version of the 20.3 Code::Blocks one of the project options is Win32 app.  It builds a 'very' minimal cpp file that displays a blank window and starts the message loop...  this is a good place to start if you've never seen a gui cpp text file that produces a blank window.  You will need to study the Win32 api and learn how to use the message loop,  how to add controls (buttons etc) to your project,  and how to debug it;  its a learning curve,  but it is rewarding education.  Get the book, "Programming Windows" fifth edition---  make sure its the fifth edition only!
The Microsoft docs are pretty good for learning the Win32 api also,  but the book is the best approach.  Take a class.
marcus

Answer (score 2):

If you want to start creating GUI programs with 'Code::Blocks' then using a 'Win32' approach looks promising.

I only recently installed 'Code::Blocks 20.03', using the defaults for the install directory, and type of installation( Full ), and was easily able to create a basic 'Win32 GUI project'.

NB: I was using Windows 10, and the basic project doesn't really do anything.

For some Microsoft documentation, see at

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/learn-to-program-for-windows

, please note at the bottom left of this page, a 'Download PDF' link.

You could start at page 18 of the pdf, which is where, 'Module 1. Your First Windows Program', starts, page 20 is illuminating.

For information on 'The Message Loop', mentioned in a previous answer, see page 24.

It might be worth bearing in mind 'Reply #3' to the question at

https://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=19537.0